Problem with Tailwind CSS and PostCSS Configuration - Tailwind doesn't applied plugins
Problem Description
I added tailwind-animation and a custom plugin to the Tailwind CSS configuration, but the classes generated by the plugin are not visible in the CSS file. IntelliSence suggests animation-delay classes, but they still are not generated in css.
If I have ensured that the Tailwind CSS and PostCSS configurations are correct, but the problem persists.
Source Code
tailwind.config.ts
import plugin from 'tailwindcss/plugin';

export default {
  content: [
    './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
  ],
  prefix: "",
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: {
        DEFAULT: "1rem",
      },
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1280px",
      },
    },
    fontWeight: {
      normal: "400",
      medium: "500",
      semibold: "600",
      bold: "700",
    },
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["var(--font-sans)", ...fontFamily.sans],
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        "background-900": "var(--background-900)",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require("tailwindcss-animate"),
    plugin(({ matchUtilities, theme }) => {
      matchUtilities(
        {
          "animation-delay": (value) => {
            return {
              "animation-delay": value,
            };
          },
        },
        {
          values: theme("transitionDelay"),
        }
      );
    }),
  ],
};

postcss.config.mjs

/** @type {import('postcss-load-config').Config} */
const config = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
  },
};

I have tried restarting the build process, but the problem persists.
Can someone help me identify what I am doing wrong?
Expected behavior
I expect the animation-delay classes to be generated correctly and to be visible in the CSS file.

Consider checking you've used an animation-delay-* class in a file covered by the content globs, and also checking the class(es) are used as full unbroken strings.

@Wongjn thanks for response, I don't kno why but after multiple rebuilds, the plugins started loading correctly. However, I am now encountering an issue where the animation-delay-* classes do not work on components within a loop. The class is not being applied to elements in the loop, while it is correctly applied to sibling elements.
